# How to build git with static linking?

Tags: linux, git, build, installation

I downloaded git source from https://github.com/git/git as a zip file.

I extracted it into /home/Desktop/denis/git (using Ubuntu).

Now the tutorial [here](http://www.lyraphase.com/wp/projects/how-to-build-git-for-a-host-with-no-compiler/) says that I should run

```
./configure --prefix=/home/denis/git-static CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -static"
```

from the above mentioned folder as a step for building git.

But the git source does not appear to have a configure file in it's root folder which I can run (only configure.ac, which I suspect is not what I'm looking for).

What am I missing here? How to build git manually?

I'm doing this because I'm trying to get git working on a shared hosting server where I'm not able to install git.

Comment: `make configure` first. That requires `autoconf`.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Read the INSTALL file in the root folder of the unzipped file, it seems there is some useful instruction in it, what I suspect:

> Alternatively you can use autoconf generated ./configure script to
>   set up install paths (via config.mak.autogen), so you can write instead

```
    $ make configure ;# as yourself
    $ ./configure --prefix=/usr ;# as yourself
    $ make all doc ;# as yourself
    # make install install-doc install-html;# as root
```

or just simply:

```
    $ make prefix=/usr all doc info ;# as yourself
    # make prefix=/usr install install-doc install-html install-info ;# as root
```

Comment: This does not build a statically linked git I think.

Answer (score 10):

The other answers did not work for me. Perhaps they will for others. What did work for me was:

1. Get the source code
2. Make a target directory
3. Enter the source directory
4. Configure
5. Build
6. Install

Use the following commands:

```
git clone git@github.com:git/git.git
mkdir git-static
cd git
./configure prefix=/path/to/git-static/ CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -static"
make
make install
```

This will leave you with a few folders in the `git-static` directory, but the executable is statically linked. It is also substantially bigger than usual (maybe 1.5 MB bigger).

Comment: Just did it on the latest version of Raspbian (targeting an OpenWRT device) and it warned me that something would still be loaded dynamically.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen That's likely because you used glibc as your C library, which really doesn't support static linking at all. The best option is to use a musl "cross compiler".

Comment: This works fine for producing static binaries (with musl as the C library). Unfortunately the remote backends (like `git-remote-https`) are not included into the git binary. Would be nice if there were some option for including these tools into the main `git` binary.