# Are there any alternatives to the git binary?

Tags: git

I want to run git on a very old distro (Fedora 4). What I don't want to do is trigger a cascade of dependency installation in order to have the git binary run. So I'm looking for alternatives to the git binary, eg. in Java or Python. If there is anywhere I can get a 32 bit static build, that might also do what I need.

Comment: Just `rsync` the files over, or copy a tarball. You will have similar dependency issues via Java or Python because the fact of the matter is that you want _recent code_ and functionality _on an ancient system_. Something has got to give.

Comment: The Java JRE is quite recent so I doubt I would face too many problems.

Comment: Build it from source.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest [**libgit2**](https://libgit2.github.com/).

This lib is portable, pure C implementation of the Git core methods. It is 100% cross-platform and has zero dependencies. 
It has many [language bindings](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2#language-bindings), like: Ruby, Python, Node.js, and many more.

Answer (score 1):

You can [build git statically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570188/how-to-build-git-with-static-linking) on another machine, with all the options you need; then you can easily transfer the resulting binary.

---

If you really want an alternative, there is [JGit](https://eclipse.org/jgit/) for Java, which provides most basic features in pure Java. *However*, this implementation is not feature-complete (at least the last time I looked), and thus will not interact properly with advanced git features, such as hooks.

Comment: I did try that the suggestions in that answer already, but the compilation failed and also gave warnings that there would still be dependencies on the target system.

Comment: @pinoyyid weird, it worked for me (although I did not follow a particular SO post, I just linked the one that was there already). Without knowing what exactly went wrong while building, I'm afraid I won't be of much help. My (on 64bit for 64bit, cross-compiling to 32bit would need another change) process was something along the lines of `make clean; make configure ; ./configure --prefix=/staticroot CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -static" NO_TCLTK=1 NO_GETTEXT=1 NO_PYTHON=1; make install` (prefixing is not necessary iirc)

Comment: Rather than cross-compile to 32bit, I simply ran up a 32 bit Fedora instance on AWS. I don't recall the detailed errors, but the warnings that there would still be dependencies was enough to put me off proceeding with that option. I'll have a look at JGit.

Comment: For future readers: you probably refer to [the problems of gethostbyname](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165306/compile-a-static-binary-which-code-there-a-function-gethostbyname), which are indeed inherent to any static linking with glibc.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the suggestions.

Without going into the background, I really need to do as little as possible to the server in question. With this in mind, the approach I eventually took to my specific problem was to sshmount the directory concerned from a more modern server and run git there.